# Twitter embed script takes too long to load

Tags: javascript, twitter, pageload

I am embedding a set of tweets fetched through the Twitter API on a single page - https://remoteclan.com/twitter-feed.

I am getting the embed for each tweet through the 'oembed' API and using it as is. But it's taking too long for the script to load and styling to apply.

Is there a way to optimize this?

P.S: I saw Twitter add a script tag in every embed. So, I tried removing all of those tags and instead having a common one at the top of the page but that didn't help either.